# Removal of Jetpack OG Tags from old blog site

Tags: filters, plugin-jetpack

www.beautifulcreationsphotography.co.uk

I have a client who used to have a Wordpress blog, however for some reason its carrying over to her new site and causing havok with Yoast.

Ive added in this filter below but it doesnt seem to have worked.

```
add_filter( 'jetpack_enable_open_graph', '__return_false' );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "a client who used to have a Wordpress blog"?

Comment: Apologies, she basically had a .blog domain, and moved it to a .co.uk domain away from WP, so all of her items are still ranking with the old domain so I'm attempting to fix this :)

Answer (score 1):

The site above does not use Jetpack's Open Graph Meta Tags. It uses Yoast SEO's own tags. In fact, on any site, if you use the Yoast SEO plugin and have activated the Open Graph meta tags under SEO > Social > Facebook, Jetpack's own Open Graph Meta Tags will never be added. Only the tags from Yoast will appear on your site. The 2 plugins are built to work well together, so you have no risk of having a duplicate set of tags if you use the 2 plugins together, and you do not need to add any code snippets.

That said, Facebook does cache information about each page on your site, so it is possible that even after you update Open Graph Meta Tags on a site, the old title / description / image is still used when sharing links on Facebook because you are seeing cached data. You can refresh that cache manually by using Facebook's Debug tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
You can click on "Scape again" there to refresh the data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not seeing a cached version of the site.

Also, try adding priority to the filter like this.

```
add_filter( 'jetpack_enable_open_graph', '__return_false', 99 );
```

Try this version as well...

```
add_filter( 'jetpack_enable_opengraph', '__return_false', 99 );
```

Try switching temporarily switching themes and checking the source code.

Comment: Hi RiddleMeThis, thankyou for this i will try this above. Its the first time ive had a client who used to have her blog on WP and has moved onto her own hosting :)

Comment: Hi @riddlemethis, I placed in the above. Used WP Fastest Cache and cleared the cache, and viewed this incognito and its still loading :S

Comment: hmmm OK, try this - remove_action('wp_head','jetpack_og_tags');  Here is an article I found https://crunchify.com/how-to-prevent-jetpack-from-doubling-open-graph-meta-tags-in-wordpress-header/